# What should be the appropriate response to error message on Vi

Tags: vim

what do you do when you get a" "tests/1-my_list.txt" E212: Can't open file for writing" error message

Comment: You look to see if you have write permissions on both the directory & file being edited. You also check that the directory exists. You also check on network share permissions, if applicable

Comment: Duplicate of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253362/etc-apt-sources-list-e212-cant-open-file-for-writing`. You are in `vim`, not `vi`.

Comment: If you have done significant editing before this happens, write it to a new file in your tmp directory first to avoid lost work. `:w /tmp/mySafeCopy`. Then open another terminal to check permissions etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `vim` editor that gives error messages with tags like `E212`, not the classic `vi` editor.

If you want to know what `E212` means, ask `vim` about it using

```
:help E212
```

This would show you the following:

```
                                                        E190 E212
  Cannot open "{filename}" for writing
  Can't open file for writing

For some reason the file you are writing to cannot be created or overwritten.
The reason could be that you do not have permission to write in the directory
or the file name is not valid.
```

(Also available at https://vimhelp.org/message.txt.html#E212)

The next step is to alleviate the issue.  In this case, the error is due to too restrictive permissions on a file or its directory, that the file path you're editing is no longer valid, or that you are editing the file as the wrong user.  In any case, you would probably investigate the path at which you're trying to write the file using `ls`, and check that the permissions and the file and directory ownerships are as you expect them to be (and that the directory actually exists).